# RSpec: comparing a hash with string keys against a hash with symbol keys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec2

Consider the following RSpec snippet:

```
it "should match" do
  {:a => 1, :b => 2}.should =~ {"a" => 1, "b" => 2}
end
```

This test fails because one hash uses symbols for keys and the other uses strings for keys.  In my case, one hash is a parsed JSON object, the other is the hash that created the object.  I'd like them to compare as equal.

Before I go writing my own matcher or coercing both hashes to have string keys, is there a matcher or technique that handles this (common) case?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could do:

```
it "should match" do
    {:a => 1, :b => 2}.stringify_keys.should =~ {"a" => 1, "b" => 2}
end
```

Comment: This is a rails method not ruby

Comment: @john.s.in.co: yes, but now that ActiveSupport can be used stand-alone (with the ability to load small subsets of it), this is an acceptable answer.

Comment: Can also use `#deep_stringify_keys` if you have nested attributes

Answer (score 19):

Assuming you have access to [Rails's ActiveSupport](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess).
You can leverage  `with_indifferent_access` to match both hashes.
Below is an example with the hashrocket Ruby syntax and the Rspec expect syntax:

```
it 'matches two hashes' do
  hash_1 = {a: 1, b: 2}.with_indifferent_access
  hash_2 = {'a' => 1, 'b' => 2}
  expect(hash_1).to match(hash_2)
end
```

Note: make sure to use `with_indifferent_access` on the hash with the symbol keys

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to write it so that it'd match the thing you're getting, like putting strings if you get strings, or putting symbols if you get symbols.

If you can't do that, what I'd do would be something like :

```
it "should match" do
  {:a => 1}.with_indifferent_access.should =~ {'a' => 1}.with_indifferent_access
end
```

Answer (score 0):

i've never heard of one, but you could have a look at active_supports `HashWithIndifferentAccess` that solves this problem within rails:  http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess